# Can I populate more fields after I have already l loaded a document on mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I want to populate aditional fields after I have already loaded one document.

I am loading my cart on a ecommerce I'm building, like this on all routes:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  Cart.findOne({session: req.cookies['express:sess']})
  .populate({ path: "products.product", select: "price name photos slug" })
  .exec(function(err, cart){
    if(err){
      return err; //TODO: PAG 500
    }
    if(cart){
      res.locals.cart = cart;
    } else {
      res.locals.cart = new Cart({ session: req.cookies['express:sess']});
    }
    next();
  });
});
```

But at one page, I'd like to have more the fields description and addons from product loaded.
I tried to just load the products, but then I miss the associated information of quantity that I have on the cart

```
var CartSchema = new Schema({
  products: [{
    product: { type: Schema.ObjectId, ref : 'Product' },
    quantity: { type: Number, default: 1}
  }],
  totalItems: { type: Number, default: 0},
  message: { type: String },
});
```

I know I could break this up in more middlewares, according to my needs on fields on different pages, or reload the cart, and I could also just go through both arrays, the products I reload and the products I loaded on the cart and do some kind of merging, but I figured that mongoose might have some way to do this.

Comment: Do you want this? http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html Or what do you mean? Where are the `description` and `addons` fields?

Comment: No, I'm already using populate: ".populate({ path: "products.product", select: "price name photos slug" })" What I'd like to do, is to populate more fields, later on when I have already loaded the document

Comment: Why don't you populate them from the start? You can do a select later based on the product id if you want to get more data later.

Comment: Because I only need those extra fields on 2 pages, out of 20+, and they are kind of big

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can actually be done:

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-populate

So in this specific case, I'd need to add this piece of code to the function that wants cart with more fields populated, and the middleware wouldn't need any changes

ES5 with callback:

```
var populate = [
  { path: "products.product", select: "price name photos slug" },
  { path: "card", select: "price name photo"}
];
var cart = res.locals.cart;
cart.populate(populate, function(err, populatedCart) {
  res.locals.cart = populatedCart;
  next();
});
```

With ES6:

```
const populate = [
  { path: "products.product", select: "price name photos slug" },
  { path: "card", select: "price name photo"}
];
res.locals.cart = await res.locals.cart.populate(populate).execPopulate();
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot "`re-populate`" a `populated field`.

How about a simple `if` to determine which fields you want to populated. For example:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var productSelect;

  // This is just an example, you can get the condition from params, body, header..
  if (req.body.isMoreField) {
    productSelect = 'add more field in here';
  }
  else {
    productSelect = 'less field here';
  }

  Cart
    .findOne({
      // ...
    })
    .populate({
      // ...
      select: productSelect,
      // ...
    })
    .exec()
    .then(function(cart) {
      // ...
    })
});
```

Comment: Hmm, I guess it just makes more sense to break it into different middlewares, as I don't have a simple argument I can use on the if.
Anyways, I selected your answer because you answered that I can't do what I wanted to do.